# Prevent javascript code to be reset and start over after page refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, local-storage

I have a rails app where in my application.js I have a `setInterval()` and inside of it an AJAX call that send a post request every minute to my controller in order to perform a create action.

```
setInterval(function(){

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/post",
          data: { parameter: value },
          success: function (data) {
             //some logic
           }       
        });

    }, 60000);
```

My problem is that if the client refresh its page every 30 sec (for exemple) the setInterval() set for 1 minute will never be triggered.

Is there a way to make my javascript code not dependent of any page refresh so that if different users arrive at different time they get to see the same thing. I guess it has to do with cookies or local storage but I have no idea how to implement that in a reliable way.

**In other word, I would like my js code to be run server side without being disrupted by page refreshes or client request which keep reseting my code.**

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Why do you expect users to refresh every 30 seconds?  Can you clarify: "if different users arrive at different time they get to see the same thing"?

Comment: 30 sec was just an exemple, what I mean is whenever the page is refreshed the setInterval is reset. So If user 1 get to the page at time1 setInterval is triggered at time1 but when another user arrive at Time2 it will reset the setInterval at Time2. I do not want that. I want the js code to run the same way without being reset. Do you know what I mean ?

Comment: Maybe you can take the user out of it by doing this server side?

Comment: In other word, I would like my js code to be run server side without being disrupted by page refreshes or client request which keep reseting the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/javan/whenever

```
every 1.minute do # 1.minute 1.day 1.week 1.month 1.year is also supported
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

Comment: not supported by heroku. I guess  I am gonna redo all my cron job with rake and use heroku scheduler

Comment: https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2016/01/23/cron-jobs-in-rails-whenever-or-scheduler-in-heroku/

Comment: does it refresh the page to execute its cron job ? do you know ? or is server side and updated in the page without refreshing the page like AJAX ?